# efficient access to large collection of objects in c#

Tags: c#, xna

im making a game using a hexagonal grid using C# XNA. The map size can be anywhere from 6 cells per side to 144. Using a bit of geometric math, this means that the maximum number of cells is 61,777! (I'm also considering going up to 216 cells per side, yielding 139,537 total cells!!!)

**What I need is an efficient way to access a given cell based on its grid coordinate.** Iterating through the whole list until finding where col == c and row == r is just not going to cut it.

The data structure also needs to be resizable (cuz beating one level means u go to the next map, which could be bigger or smaller). So I can't use 2D arrays (correct me if I'm wrong). Right now I'm thinking about List since it actually does have a `ElementAt<i>`. But a `List<List<CELL>>` seems cumbersome. A dynamic 2D array of CELLs seems best but unless Im gravely mistaken, such arrays need to be a fixed size in C#.

Please also let me know the inside workings of any possibilities. How do Lists store their data anyway? (besides holding a pointer---I need to know any other overhead). Are they really random access or does `ElementAt<i>` actually iterate i times to get to that element?

Other radical thoughts I had are like a binary tree except base-6, like splitting the map into hexagonal sectors, each of which contain a bunch of cells. With these radical ideas, however, I can't wrap my head around any implementation details :(

Comment: A list of lists is not cumbersome.

Comment: Lists store their data in arrays.

Comment: You might also consider a `Dictionary<rowKey, Dictionary<columnKey, value>>`. Access times for dictionaries are O(1) based upon keys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057715/access-times-for-dictionary-hashset

Comment: Lists also expose an indexer, you don't need to use `ElementAt`. Index operations are O(1), there is no reason to use a dictionary.

Comment: Comparison of access times between List and Dictionary: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time

Comment: That benchmark is on the time to scan for the existence of a value in a collection, not to look up a value at a specific index, of course it's linear time to execute a loop over a list.

Comment: Why do you say `List<List<CELL>>` seems cumbersome?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot thanx, was about to say that dotnetperls reference says lists are O(N) !!!! Well I'll use nested Lists then. 

...And nested lists are cumbersome because, well, 2D arrays are much simpler syntax arent they? If lists are based on arrays in C#, then why cant C# have variable-sized 2D arrays...?

Comment: OKAY, i found a way to use 2D arrays for this; `CELL CellGrid[,] = new CELL[6, 6];` Then when a need to resize it, i clear it first and then `CellGrid = new CELL[12, 12];` am i correct in assuming that when assigning a new array, the old one and all its cells gets cleaned up in the garbage collector?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nested `List<List<T>>`. As others mentioned, based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation; setting
>   the property is also an O(1) operation.

I suggest you write an interface like below and then implement it in case you decide to change the implementation later.

```
public interface IGrid<T>
{
    T Get(int x, int y);
    void Set(int x, int y, T value);
    void Insert(int x, int y, T value);
    void Remove(int x, int y);
}

public class Grid<T>: IGrid<T>
{
    private List<List<T>> _data = new List<List<T>>();

    public T Get(int x, int y)
    {
        return _data[x][y];
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, T value)
    {
        _data[x][y] = value;
    }

    public void Insert(int x, int y, T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Remove(int x, int y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can write something like:

```
        var myGrid = new Grid<Cell>();
        myGrid.Set(0, 0, new Cell("Blah"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Dictionary

documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
usage: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

You can Index it either with an object you create(like a Point object) or a string like this:

```
string key = r+","+c;
```

I would chose the key as string since it will be easier the speed increase you get from making it a point won't be much.

Considering you do it with a string key like this:

```
dictionary Dictionary<string,Cell> = new Dictionary<string,cell>();
```

You could then make a method that creates a key to make sure you get the right key all the time

```
public string createKey(int row,int col)
{
return r+","+c;
}

public string createKey(Cell cell)
{
return createKey(cell.row,cell.col);
}
```

when retrieving the cell you do a call like this

```
int c=0;
int r=0;
Cell cell = dictionary[createKey(r,c)].doSomethingWithCell();
```

Hope this helps